# How to get the VM's directory on Vagrant

Tags: ruby, vagrant, virtualbox, provisioning, vagrantfile

I need to create some extra disks on my VirtualBox VM depending on some external configuration, but those disks must be self-contained, I mean, under the VM's directory. I did it with success but, forcing the VM name (making it predictable), **however, I can't force the name on my environment due to some restrictions**. Some people will work simultaneously in different branches and in different directories and forcing the name is not a good idea for this particular case, it needs to be dynamic. Any idea for solving this problem will be much appreciated.

```
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.9.7"

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|

  config.vm.define "mylinux-vm", autostart: false do |this|

    this.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    this.vm.hostname = "my-linuxvm"
    this.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.memory = 2048; 
      vb.cpus = 2

      # What is the directory where this VM is going to be created?
      # I need to create other disk files under the VM directory
      # is going to be something like:
      #    $HOME/VirtualBox VMs/<current_dir_name>_mylinux-vm_<timestamp>
      # How can I get this directory?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the name of that folder by doing the following, and refer to it in your Vagrantfile:

```rb
vb_memory = 2048
vb_cpus = 2
vb_name = "mylinuxvm-foobar-mem#{vb_memory}-cpu#{vb_cpus}"

...

this.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.memory = vb_memory; 
  vb.cpus = vb_cpus
  vb.name = vb_name  
  # Setting the above would create a directory like this : 
  # $HOME/VirtualBox VMs/mylinuxvm-foobar-mem2048-cpu2
end
```

This would keep the name of the folder unique and you can also refer to it throughout the Vagrantfile as `vb_name`

Comment: I made it work with this approach: forcing the VM name (making it predictable), however, *I can't do it on my environment due to some restrictions*.

Comment: Please elaborate on the restrictions you are referring to.

Comment: The restriction is **I can't force the name** because eventually someone may wants to run the provisioning task on their workstation and will raise errors if they already have a VM with the name on VirtualBox, I need it dynamic like it is.

Comment: Okay, so you mean that your name needs to be unique and yet predictable, am I right?

Comment: Unique, yes. As long I have a way to read this property from somewhere I am happy about that.

Comment: Would you read this property only in your Vagrantfile or somewhere else that has no access to this Vagrantfile?

Comment: Just from the Vagrant file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189291/discussion-between-bitsapien-and-wellington-souza).

Comment: You could also use `git branch` to append to your VMs name.